# Core Data, can't retrieve/set to my properties. Most common mistake?

Tags: iphone, ios5, core-data, uiviewcontroller

SUBJECT: Core Data, can't retrieve/set to my properties from VC's. Most common mistake?

*Searched through this site but **could not quite get the answered I need** (many good tips though), so thought I post this question in hope it will resolve my issue I've had for a couple of weeks now! Yes, very frustrating, you probably know the feeling! So ANY help would be great - thank's!  :-)*

### Oveview:

iOS 5.1 project. Got Core Data working (tested in main.h/NSLog) but I'm **having trouble retrieving and setting Entities properties (data) from other view controllers**. Xcode recognizes my singelton "AppContent" found in the AppDelegate from other view controllers, but not the entity name and it's properties.

#### **What is the most common mistake regarding this?**

I get a feeling of that I've just missed to importing some file in the right place etc...

### Some more details;

FYI: I'm trying to use a recommended method by Matt Campell, that creates a singleton in the AppDelegate that can be **used all over the app** to work with the managedObjectContext from any view controllers, and retrieve and save data to Core Data and it's entities and it's respective properties. This is done by importing the following two files to the app;

**appContent.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Contest.h"  // Root Entity in CD model
#import "Player.h"

@interface AppContent : NSObject

+(AppContent *)sharedContent;

@property(strong, readonly) id rootObject;

-(void)save;
-(void)rollback;

@end
```

**appContent.m**

```
#import "AppContent.h"
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface AppContent()

-(NSURL *)dataStoreURL;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@end

@implementation AppContent
NSManagedObjectModel *_managedObjectModel;
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *_persistentStoreCoordinator;
NSManagedObjectContext *_managedObjectContext;
id _rootObject;

static AppContent *singletonInstance = nil;

+ (AppContent *)sharedContent{
    @synchronized(self){
        if (singletonInstance == nil)
            singletonInstance = [[self alloc] init];

        return(singletonInstance);
    }
}


- (NSURL *)dataStoreURL {

    NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];

    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DataStore.sql"]];
}

- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    if (_managedObjectModel) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    _managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];    
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                               configuration:nil
                                                         URL:[self dataStoreURL]
                                                     options:nil
                                                       error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved Core Data error with persistentStoreCoordinator: %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }    

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    if (_managedObjectContext) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    if ([self persistentStoreCoordinator]) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[self persistentStoreCoordinator]];
    }

    return _managedObjectContext;
}

-(id)rootObject{
    if(_rootObject)
        return _rootObject;

// #warning Replace [CHANGE] with your root object entity name
    NSString *entityName = @"Contest";
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
    request.entity = entity;
    NSArray *listOfObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:request
                                                error:nil];
    if([listOfObjects count] == 1){
        _rootObject = [listOfObjects lastObject];
        return _rootObject;
    }
    _rootObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:entityName
                                            inManagedObjectContext:context];

    // Adding some testdata (only first time...)
    // Contest
    Contest *c = _rootObject;
    c.name = @"Big Game 1";

    // Players
    Player *p1 = (Player *) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Player"
                                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
    p1.name = @"Player One";
    [c addPlayersObject:p1];

    Player *p2 = (Player *) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Player"
                                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];
    p2.name = @"Player Two";
    [c addPlayersObject:p2];

    [self save];

    return _rootObject;
}

-(void)save{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    if([context hasChanges])
        [context save:&error];
    if(error)
        NSLog(@"Warning: Error saving to data store.  %@", error);
}

-(void)rollback{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    if([context hasChanges])
        [context rollback];
}

@end
```

### Here are the model files (created by CD model editor);

**Contest.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Player;

@interface Contest : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *players;
@end

@interface Contest (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addPlayersObject:(Player *)value;
- (void)removePlayersObject:(Player *)value;
- (void)addPlayers:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removePlayers:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

**Contest.m**

```
#import "Contest.h"
#import "Player.h"

@implementation Contest

@dynamic name;
@dynamic players;

@end
```

**Player.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Contest;

@interface Player : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Contest *contests;

@end
```

**Player.m**

```
#import "Player.h"
#import "Contest.h"


@implementation Player

@dynamic name;
@dynamic contests;

@end
```

### Here is a view controller

Trying to get hold of the Core Data Entities and it properties here, but Xcode see's the appContent but don't recognize it and when building it gives error "Can't find property player"...

**contestPlayerVC.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "AppContent.h"


@interface contestPlayerVC : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *playerNameField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *playerMailField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *playerSaveButton;

@property (weak, nonatomic) AppContent *content;

// Test
// @property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;


- (IBAction)playerChooseImage:(UIButton *)sender;

- (IBAction)dismissModal:(UIButton *)sender;

- (IBAction)hideKeyboard:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)playerSave:(UIButton *)sender;

@end
```

**contestPlayerVC.m**
Not showing hole file since problem is in the method viewDidLoad...

```
#import "contestPlayerVC.h"

@interface contestPlayerVC ()

@end

@implementation contestPlayerVC
@synthesize playerNameField, playerMailField, playerSaveButton, content;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // Call 1 - seems to work ok
    self.content = [AppContent sharedContent];

////// Call 2 - gives error, can't find property "player" - WHY?
    // Trying to set textfield to CD Entity "Player" and it's property "name"
    self.playerNameField.text = self.content.player.name;

    NSLog(@"Player is: %@", self.content.player.name);

    // Call 3 - works ok
    NSLog(@"Content is: %@", self.content.description);

}
...
```

### Any tips or suggestions? Thanks!  :-)

Btw: Sorry about the long post, I'm not sure about how else describe my problem well enough for anyone to understand it. If you read it all - I'm impressed and I'll be real happy to if you help me solve this. Probably some basic thing I totally missed. Thank's ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@user1578933 Ok, let's back up a second and think about what each piece is responsible for:

- **Contest** is the root (first) object responsible for everything related to a contest including the name and list of players
- **Player** is responsible for everything about a player including the player's name
- **AppContent** is responsible for managing the object graph (retrieving the object graph so you can use it and remembering what the user adds and removes)
- **contestPlayerVC** is responsible for presenting content (from AppContent)

In your app, everything starts with **Contest**.  In your **AppContent** implementation you have code that generates that property **rootObject** and this is where the **Contest** object is created for the first time.

**NOTE** You have that defined as **id** because you are copying this code directly for our program, but you could also have defined **rootObject** as type **Contest** like this:

```
-(Contest *) rootObject;
```

This your point of entry to your object graph.  The idea is that you will access **AppContent** (using the Singleton  pattern) and then retrieve the **Contest** object.  The **Contest** object will have the **NSSet** object collection that contains references to each player in the collection.

Here's an example of how you would use this in your view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.content = [AppContent sharedContent];

    //get reference to the root object contest
    Contest *theContest = (Contest *)self.content.rootObject;

    //get an array based reference to the players in theContest
    NSArray *players = [theContest.players allObjects];

    //Example of getting a reference to an individual player:
    Player *p1 = [players objectAtIndex:0];

}
```

This is essentially how you would add this content to your view controller; for a table view controller you would use the index path row property to find out what player goes in what table view cell (see cellForRowAtIndexPath).

@user1578933 - after reading this post and also the ones you left on [Mobile App Mastery Institute](http://institute.mobileappmastery.com/iostrainingpack/core-data/) it seems like you are missing some understanding of the object graph and how all these object relationships are organized in general.  I've recently added some additional content about how to use and think about the [Objective-C object graph here](http://institute.mobileappmastery.com/iostrainingpack/introduction-to-ios-sdk/).  Also, I would carefully look over the sections on Objective-C, Table Views and Core Data again.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was just what I was looking for! Now I can continue working w Core Data and your AppContent concept, since I now have a better understanding of it. And yes, I will be returning to your site to read up on the object graph, in your updated material. Thank's again :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your error, not being able to find a `player` property on `self.content`, is because your AppContent class doesn't declare any property of that name. Let's walk through your code one line at a time:

```
self.content = [AppContent sharedContent];
```

Now `self.content` is an object of type AppContent, and so any future calls to `self.content.something` will look for visible methods or properties declared on that class (usually in "AppContent.h").

```
self.playerNameField.text = self.content.player.name;
```

We're looking here for a property named `player` in an AppContent object, which has as its header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Contest.h"  // Root Entity in CD model
#import "Player.h"

@interface AppContent : NSObject

+(AppContent *)sharedContent;

@property(strong, readonly) id rootObject;

-(void)save;
-(void)rollback;

@end
```

Nowhere in there is a `@property` named `player` - you have a `rootObject` property, and you import the "Player.h" header, but you never declare the property you're trying to access. You'll need to add a line like:

```
@property(strong) Player * player;
```

and either `@synthesize` it in your "AppContent.m" file, or provide the appropriate accessor methods to back that property.

Comment: rootObject should probably be typed as Contest instead of id as well.

Comment: @Tim & jrturton, Thank's for the Quick input/help! Will test this tomorrow(8.20pm here in Sweden now).

Comment: Quick followup: and by adding the player property to it, Will I be able to get to the 'name' attribute of the Entity Player?

Comment: @user1578933: you tell me - does the Player object expose a `@property` called `name`? (You'd be looking in "Player.h".)

Comment: @Tim, **yes** it does and it's a NSString, so it should work. I'll find out within the hour when I start testing it. Need to see it working in my code, before I can check of your answer as correct. Again thanks for a very good and explaining answer!

Comment: Added this to property AppContent.h;
`@property(strong) Player * player;`
so it now finds the property "player", but still don't find the attribute "name". It gives me error "Property 'name' not found on objects id"

Comment: @jrturton, I then tried to also add `@property(strong) Contest * rootObject;` to appContent.h & synthesize it i .m, but I still get the same error. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Tim any more suggestions? Feels really close to solving this now!

Comment: Sorry, there was I Xcode issue: I deleted the old codelines and retyped them in the VC - know it finds `self.content.player.name`.

Comment: @Tim, @jrturton **Followup:** The above `player.name` gives me just the value "(null)" even though the CD entity Player has a property "hard" set in AppContent.m on startup(shows in NSLog to), that is "Player One". What's missing for this to work properly? Thanks :-)

Comment: Do I maybe need to do a fetchrequest before I can get something out of the `player.name`? Is that why it's "(null)"?

Comment: Tips: Got SQLite DB Browser up an running now, so I can see whats happening in the db while working with Core Data. [http://stackoverflow.com/q/11862995/1578933]

Comment: @Mac: Are you sure that you actually set something for the `player` property? If your player is `nil`, then calling `[player name]` will also return `nil`, giving you a "null" name value. Check that you assign a valid Player instance to `player` in AppContent - this may involve a fetch request from your Core Data stack.

Comment: @Tim, tested this and it works;`AppContent *ac = [AppContent sharedContent];
 
 Contest *con = ac.rootObject;
 
 NSLog(@"CD TEST in contestPlayerVC: con.name = %@", con.name);
 
 NSSet *players = con.players;
 
 [players enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, BOOL *stop) {
  NSLog(@"CD TEST in contestPlayerVC: player.name = %@", [obj name]);
 }];` it gives this result in NSLog;`CD TEST in contestPlayerVC: con.name = Big Game 1 \nCD TEST in contestPlayerVC: player.name = Player Two \nCD TEST in contestPlayerVC: player.name = Player One`

Comment: When Matt Campell, who created the AppConted, describe the how & why, he said this (hope this helps clearing it up); "AppContent will be used as an interface to entities. Core Data will be encapsulated and hidden behind AppContent. Project objects can only access to the data model through AppContent."

Comment: @Tim - I'm still stuck on this... Just need to know how to call & edit the AppContent (CoreData Content) from another view controller. What to import, what properties to set and how to do the actual call.